# Capital Punishment - The Clock is Ticking

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, geography, crosswords, seasonal

A little spooky teaser for the coming Halloween...

[image]

A minor tag that suits but can't be put in due to the tag limit is omitted.

Hints:

1

> Why cities instead of random clues?

2

> Title is hint...

3

> The Clock is Ticking...

4

> Sometimes things that are often known in the form of numbers can be converted into other things...

5

> Sergeant, what's the time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(I'm really just picking up the pieces left behind by M Oehm here; if you like this, go upvote one of his things.)

If you take the

> cities he has found

and find

> their time zones (as hinted at by all the stuff about clocks)

and interpret them via

> military time zone names (as hinted at by e.g. the last hint)

then you get

> WHSAAD for the across clues and ATTEI for the down ones.

Now

> these are an anagram of the seasonally and thematically appropriate message: DEATH AWAITS.

Note:

> There isn't anything in the puzzle to indicate *what* anagram to take. (Setter has confirmed in TSL chat.)

Comment: so nicely done! this puzzle can finally rest. i'll let this answer sit for awhile to get some upvotes before i award you the green check :)

Answer (score 16):

**Partial answer**

The cryptic clues ...

> ... have no definition. Instead, the title of the crossword puzzle, "Capital Punishment", gives a hint: All answers are national or state capitals.

**Across**

**3** No, that is, in lieu of two, a single beheaded homicide leader precedes

> HONOLULU, capital of Hawaii, USA
>   H(omicide) + (m)ONO + L(ie)U without IE twice, not sure about the order

**4** Limits of source removes, intrinsically the energy would be lost

> PERTH, capital of West Australia
>   PER SE - S(ourc)E + TH(e) - E (energy)

**5** Tip for buying muppet – by Peter

> BELMOPAN, capital of Belize
>   B(uying) + ELMO + (Peter) PAN

**6** A broken shank is leading

> KINSHASA, capital of the Democratic Republic of Congo
>   SHANK IS* + A

**8** Demolish Cal's cabana

> CASABLANCA, principal city of Morocco
>   CAL'S CABANA*

**10** Call me after one

> DUBAI, capital of the Emirate of Dubai in the UAE (Thanks to Alconja!)
>   DUB (call) + A + I

**Down**

**1** Sly glares I received

> ALGIERS, capital of Algeria (Thanks to Weather Vane!)
>   GLARES* around I

**2** False hope with early sign of new Chinese leader from the east

> PHOENIX, capital of Arizona
>   HOPE* + N(ew) + (Jinping) XI<

**3** Relish scattered moment. Embraced? Behold!

> HERMOSILLO, capital of Sonora, Mexico
>   RELISH* around MO + LO

**7** Member of travel amateurs returned

> MALE, capital of the Maldives
>   trav_EL AM<_ateurs

**9** A mind, having taken in ecstasy

> SEOUL, capital of South Korea
>   E (ecstasy, drug) in SOUL

The grid:

> ```
>                                  A
>                  P   H O N O L U L U
>          P E R T H   E           G
>                  O   R           I
>                B E L M O P A N   E
>                  N   O           R
>                K I N S H A S A   S
>                  X   I
>                      L       M
>            C A S A B L A N C A
>                E     O       L
>                O             E
>              D U B A I
>                L
> ```

The overall answer:

> There is an answer of eleven letters (two words: 5, 6) to this crossword puzzle. I haven't found it. There are eleven clues whose first letters are APHMS HPBKCT and eleven common lights: HLHEM ISSLAU. Using the states that the answers are capitals of doesn't yield anything promising, either.
>
>  It's also not clear whether the answer is another capital of whether it fits with the Halloween theme. The answer could also be a punishment, as hinted at in the title. Kuala Lumpur and Addis Abbaba are capitals that match the letter count (5, 6). Buenos Aires is a near miss. I don't see how to make any of those, though.
>
>  For what it's worth, here's a list of the answers:
>
> ```
>         Honolulu        Hawaii                  US-HI
>         Perth           Western Australia       AU-WA
>         Belmopan        Belize                  BZ
>         Kinshasa        Congo                   CG
>         Casablanca      Morocco                 MA
>         Dubai           Dubai                   AE-DU
>
>         Algiers         Algeria                 DZ
>         Phoenix         Arizona                 US-AZ
>         Hermosillo      Sonora                  MX-SON
>         Male            Maldives                MV
>         Seoul           South Korea             KR
> ```

Comment: You are ahead - I can't catch up, so I offer no 1, rot13(Zl nafjre vf nytvref ohg gur pyhr unf na reebe, yratgu frira abg fvk) and no. 10, rot13(V fnl vg vf ghavf ohg V qba'g xabj jul).

Comment: @WeatherVane: Thank you! I'll put that into my answer. I'm not sure about how 10 works, either.

Comment: 10 is rot13(QHONV - QHO (pnyy) N (bar) V (zr, nsgre); pncvgny bs Rzvengr bs Qhonv va gur HNR)

Comment: Technically, Alconja actually pointed out that rot13(Qhonv vf bayl gur pncvgny bs 'gur Rzvengr bs Qhonv', abg gur ragver HNR (juvpu jbhyq or Noh Qunov).) This would affect your explanation and summary table, not sure if it impacts on the final solution...

Comment: Technically, you are right. `:)`

Comment: The title could be a reference to rot13(gvzr mbarf), although at least the most obvious interpretation doesn't seem to produce anything meaningful...